How to Improve Viewer Quality for NWD Models from Autodesk Construction Cloud and Exclude Rooms as Solids?
I’m working with a model in .nwd format hosted in Autodesk Construction Cloud. I’ve created issues in the ACC and loaded the model into a custom viewer using the Autodesk Viewer API. However, the model quality in the custom viewer is significantly lower compared to the quality in Autodesk’s own viewer. I’ve attached comparison images for reference:


Here’s the code I’m using to initialize and load the viewer:
export const initViewer = async (token, urn, setViewerIsReady) => {
  const options = {
    env: "AutodeskProduction2", //'AutodeskStaging', //'AutodeskProduction',
    api: "streamingV2",
    accessToken: token,
  };

  const viewerContainer = document.getElementById("modelViewer");

  const config = {
    extensions: ["Autodesk.AEC.Minimap3DExtension"],
  };

  let viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(viewerContainer, config);

  const documentUrn = `urn:${urn}`;

  Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => {
    const startCode = viewer.start();

    if (startCode > 0) {
      console.error("Failed to create a Viewer: WebGL not supported.");
      return;
    }

    window.ACC_ISSUE_VIEWER = viewer;

    viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, () => {
      setViewerIsReady(true);
    });

    Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(
      documentUrn,
      (viewerDocument) => {
        const defaultModel = viewerDocument.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
        viewer
          .loadDocumentNode(viewerDocument, defaultModel, {
            globalOffset: new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
          })
          .then(() => {});
        console.log("Document loaded successfully");
      },
      () => {
        console.error("Failed fetching Forge manifest");
      }
    );
  });
};

Low quality rendering:
The model quality in my custom viewer is significantly lower than in the official Autodesk viewer. How can I improve the rendering quality in my custom viewer to match the official viewer?
Rooms loaded as solids:
The viewer is also loading rooms as solid geometry. Is there a way to exclude rooms from being loaded or displayed in the viewer?
I would greatly appreciate any advice or recommendations to resolve these issues. Thank you!
Note: I use React.js

I have noticed that if I remove the global offset (globalOffset: new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0)), the model is no longer distorted. However, the point of view for the issue states configured in ACC is lost. Is there a way to maintain the configured point of view while avoiding the distortion?

This kind of geometry distortion is typically caused by the design being too far from the origin. If the X/Y/Z values in the individual geometry vertices get too large, you start running into floating point precision issues on the GPU, causing exactly this kind of distortion. Moving the model closer to origin (as you've already found) is recommended to avoid this issue.

Thanks for your reply. I have read in other questions about the issue regarding the distance to the origin point. My problem is that I am importing the model from ACC, and I need to retrieve the issues along with their viewerState. When I set globalOffset: new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0), distortion occurs, but the viewerState of the issue works as expected. However, if I remove the globalOffset: new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0), the distortion disappears, but the viewerState takes me to a different location than where I saved the issue in ACC.
What would be the best approach to retrieve the issue within the model without causing distortion while also ensuring that the viewerState points to the correct location?
